# Excluded variables from regression

Tags: statistics, spss

SPSS keeps excluding a variable from my regression, and I am not exactly sure why. Here is where I started:

```
Perf = ILTProt + LProt + AbsoluteFitProt + Male + EDUC + Age + C
```

I then decided to switch out the AbsoluteFitProt variable for a different measure of a similar thing to give:

```
Perf = ILTProt + LProt + FitProt + Male + EDUC + Age + C
```

But SPSS keeps omitting ILTProt so I end up with

```
Perf = LProt + FitProt + Male + EDUC + Age + C
```

Does anyone know why this may be? Or How to fix it?

Comment: Please do not repeat tags in question titles.

Answer (score 0):

So this was due to co-linnearity between ILTProt and FitProt. Not sure how to fix it though, but have instead just decided to omit the excluded variable.

Answer (score 0):

This (a variable being automatically omitted from a regression model) typically occurs when the variable is a constant or has perfect colinearity/correlation with another variable. So check if `ILTProt` & `FitProt`, have a perfect correlation?